# ngRepeat variable name

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

How can I know the name of the variable used within the `ng-repeat` directive?

I have two nested directives like this:

```
<div data-ng-list-item-multi ng-repeat="item in items | isArray">
  ...
</div>
```

Then, the directive needs to know how many elements exist inside that `item` variable (that is an array), but it is exposed through property named after the property I chose for in the `ng-repeat` clause:

```
.directive("ngListItemMulti", function(){
    return {
        restrict: 'AE',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs, controller) {
            var itemCount = scope.item.length;

            ...
        }
      };
})
```

The problem is that I choose to use `ng-repeat="whatever in items"` it will stop working, because then I should use `scope.whatever.length`.

Is there anyway to know the name of that selected variable?

Cheers.

**UPDATE**: The question is about how to know the name of the property ... but without indicating it somewhere else.

Answer (score 4):

Create a two-way binding scope. You'll have to pass the variable name though.

```
<div data-ng-list-item-multi item-multi="item" ng-repeat="item in items | isArray">
  ...
</div>


.directive("ngListItemMulti", function(){
    return {
        restrict: 'AE',
        scope: {
            itemMulti: '='
        },
        link: function(scope, element, attrs, controller) {
            var itemCount = scope.itemMulti.length;

            ...
        }
      };
})
```

Comment: actually you accidentally write  item-multi="item" instead of item-multi="items" (s in the end). the item is not knows at this point but the items does.

Comment: Item is defined within the scope, it fires for each one in `ng-repeat`. My code is tested and works.

Comment: Oh sorry, I didn't see you are adding an attribute with the var name! In that case why do I need an isolated storage? I can do `scope[attrs["item-multi"]]`, right? You are not finding out the name of the var, you are indicating it!

Answer (score 0):

You can use what angular uses within the ngRepeat code. use:

`var expression = $attr.ngRepeat;` to get the expression

`var match = expression.match(/^\s*([\s\S]+?)\s+in\s+([\s\S]+?)(?:\s+track\s+by\s+([\s\S]+?))?\s*$/)` to break expression

`var collection = match[2];` to get collection

`$scope.$watchCollection(rhs, fn);` to watch collection

Then in the watch function (fn) you can use you can use the collection.length;
if you don't want to watch you can use $parse to get the value.

Answer (score 0):

In order to solve your problem, what we want to be able to do is separate the scope inside a directive from the scope outside, and then map the outer scope to a directive's inner scope. This can be accomplished using an **isolate scope**. To do this, we will add a `scope` property to our directive object:

```
scope: {
  item: '=item'
}
```

Our full directive might now look something like this:

```
myApp.directive('listItemMulti', function($log) {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    link: function(scope, elem) {
        var length = scope.item.length;
        ...
    },
    scope: {
      item: '=item'
    }
  }
});
```

This can be used in our html like this:

```
<div ng-controller="SampleCtrl">
  <list-item-multi ng-repeat="whatever in items" item="whatever">
  </list-item-multi>
</div>
```

What we are doing here is designating a variable in our directive that we can bind to when we use our directive in our html. Here we've added the variable `item`. This can now be assigned to by using the variable name as an html attribute on our custom element. Notice how we've assigned `whatever` to the attribute `item`. Now, within our `link` function, our `scope` variable will contain the value that `item` was bound to. This allows us to designate specific variables that we want to be visible within out directive, but also provides an extra layer of indirection that prevents our code from being brittle. We can now change the name of the outside variable to whatever we feel like without needing to change anything within our directive.

Also, notice that I have renamed your directive to `listItemMulti` instead of `ngListItemMulti`. The `ng` prefix of directives is a convention specific to the built in angular directives. You should avoid using this prefix in your custom directives so that you can prevent any accidental naming conflicts that might occur. Often, it is best practice to give all your directives some standard prefix that relates to the name of the application. For instance, if I was developing an app for Stack Overflow, I might prefix all my directives with `so`.

Here is a plnkr with a working example: http://plnkr.co/edit/BdtWcuUz34GxhkrKWCwS?p=preview

The documentation on directives, and specifically isolate scope can be found here: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive. (ctrl+f "Isolating the Scope of a Directive").

Hope this helps :-)

Comment: Thanks pje, but you are not finding out the name of the var, you are indicating it in that `item="whatever"`attribute. The idea is to find the name, without indicating it.

Comment: @vtortola I am not sure that there is a way to do what you are asking in AngularJS.